# Which image php extension install for dompdf

Tags: image, dompdf

I am trying to create a pdf with [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) but I get this error when it is trying to add an image.

```
Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Function imagecreatefromgif() not found.  Cannot convert gif image: E:\APBPEVALUACIONDES/imagenes/header.gif.  Please install the image PHP extension.' in E:\APBPEVALUACIONDES\dompdf6\include\cpdf_adapter.cls.php:470
```

Any one could suggest me the extension for this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`imagecreatefromgif()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) is part of the [GD PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). In dompdf 0.5.1 or earlier you could get away without GD if you stuck to PNG, but in 0.6.0 GD is pretty much a requirement. Unless your document does not include images, which it obviously does.

Check your PHP configuration. So long as you're using 0.6.0 you can look for any other red flags in the configuration page located at dompdf/www/setup.php (accessed via your web server).

And just FYI, here's a quick rundown of the requirements for full functionality:

- PHP5+ (required)
- [DOM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (required, enabled by default)
- GD extension
- [MBString extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)
- [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to true if you need to access "remote" files (that would be file references using a URL with domain, e.g. http://example.com/image.png). This is sometimes disabled by hosting providers.
- read/write access to the directories specified by DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR, DOMPDF_FONT_DIR, and DOMPDF_FONT_CACHE by the process running dompdf (typically your web server).

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same problem. i did 2 things.

1. DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE  set to true at  pdf\dompdf_config.custom.inc.php &  pdf\dompdf_config.custom.inc.php
2. i tried with .jpg file.

   it worked for me!!